# How to do three-tiered multi-site?

Tags: multisite

I see references in the CiviCRM wiki to ["L2" and "L3" multi-site configurations](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi-org+and+multi-site+musing) - but no documentation on how to do L3 multi-site.  Can anyone explain the correct configuration for 3-level multisite?

Comment: Hi Jon - not sure yet about SE protocol but it might help to understand your needs. For example, we have delivered multi-level permissioned solutions using the Extended Permissions extension. This can go as many levels deep as required. For example if Org X has permissioned relationship to Org Y, which has permissioned relationship to Org Z, then any 'officer' with a permissioned relationship to an Org at any point in the hiearachy will only see the Contacts that their Org, or and sub-Orgs have permissioned relationships to.

Comment: May have explained it better here https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35633.msg151426.html#msg151426 Obviously if you need Drupal sites at each tier then yes the L2, L3 model is one to go for, but can't comment on that since while we have done multiple cases for L1, L2 I don't think we have needed to provide for L3

Comment: Pete - if you post that comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted!  This is very helpful, thank you.

Comment: cool. perhaps the title should be - how to provide multi-tiered access control, since the phrase 'multi-site' does relate to L1, L2 etc

Comment: Jon G - you were going to accept the below? and perhaps update title?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure yet about SE protocol but there are other options than L1 L2 etc especially if there is no requirement to have separate Drupal domains for each component. For example, we have delivered multi-level permissioned solutions using the [Related Permissions](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) extension. This can go as many levels deep as required.

For example if Org X has permissioned relationship to Org Y, which has permissioned relationship to Org Z, then any 'officer' with a permissioned relationship to an Org at any point in the hiearachy will only see the Contacts that their Org, or and sub-Orgs have permissioned relationships to.

This is also explained [here](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35633.msg151426.html#msg151426) and a blog is well overdue. Obviously if you need Drupal sites at each tier then yes the L2, L3 model is one to go for.

Comment: I can't seem to find this "Extended Permissions" extension that you mentioned. Is it the [Relationship Permissions as ACL](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) ?

Comment: After reading again [this](https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35633.msg151426.html#msg151426) I see that's the extension.

Comment: yep sorry about misleading name - i got thrown by the phrase "Transitive permissions go only one step" and thought I was on the wrong one. Perhaps she meant 'one direction'