# Multi-level Organization ACL Permissions

Tags: groups, acl

For my first CiviCRM implementation I need to set it up for an organization that has several national branches, each with a number of centres.
Contacts belong to a centre and therefore its country.

Role permissions are needed at different levels:
- local managers should be able to view/edit only contacts within their own centre;
- national managers should be able to view/edit only contacts within the same country;
- international managers can access all contacts.

[This page](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi-level+Organization+ACL+Permissions) of the CiviCRM's wiki is a promising start to give ideas, but it never got completed.

I've made a few attempts using Option Groups, Custom Fields mapped to Smart Groups, but I did not really go anywhere also because the idea of managing about 170 centres in 22 countries that way seems a bit cumbersome.

Can anyone give me ideas on the best approach to handle this ?

Answer (score 5):

While it's more work to set up, I think you'd be very well served by taking advantage of [multi-site](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Multi+Site+Installation) capabilities of CiviCRM, especially in conjunction with the excellent [Multi-site Permissioning extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/org.civicrm.multisite).  That said - I'm very nervous recommending these tools to someone who hasn't set up CiviCRM before!  It takes a fair amount of web development know-how to get this all working.

This would get you two-tier permissioning for "free".  You need three tiers - local, national, international.  I'd probably give each local group their own site - using [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) for Drupal or [Wordpress multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network).  Then I'd handle the national level via ACLs.  Hopefully someone might also give good advice on [my related question here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/505/how-to-do-three-tiered-multi-site).

The alternative approach is to write a custom permission extension.  This has a performance benefit, and also leads to much easier management.  However, this requires a much higher level of skill!  I'd say the two shops with proven expertise here are [Fuzion](http://www.fuzion.co.nz/contact) and [JMA Consulting](http://jmaconsulting.biz/).  If you're a developer yourself, the Multisite Permissioning extension above is a good example to get you started.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if your local groups correspond to counties (or county equivalents).  If so, you might install the [local permissions extension we built for the National Democratic Institute](https://github.com/nditech/org.ndi.civi-local-permissions). It allows you to grant certain roles permission to view/edit contacts in their county, and others permission over their state, all using the contacts' addresses (avoiding having to create 340+ groups, one for each center's contacts and one for each center's leaders.